# Hola, como le puedo dar estilos a este select, me gustaria que cuando pase el mouse por una opcion cambie ese color azul. Gracias

Tags: css, reactjs

este es mi codigo, estoy tratando de dar estilos a la clase Option pero no logro cambiar el color

````
         <option className='option'>Activo</option>
         <option className='option'>Inactivo</option>
    </Form.Select>```
````

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: Eso es código HTML, supongo que te refieres a `hover` de CSS. Para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas investiga un poco antes de preguntar.

Answer (score -3):

Puede usar estilos en línea en un componente para cambiar el color del texto según la selección de los usuarios.style={{color: incorrectColor}}

Deberá evaluar si la respuesta seleccionada es correcta o incorrecta, actualizar el estado y luego actualizar el color en el componente.

Eche un vistazo a esta respuesta usando un operador ternario para manipular estilos: [¿Es posible cambiar el color del texto según el valor? (Reaccionar nativo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904338/it-is-possible-to-change-the-text-color-depending-on-the-value-react-native)